# genfromtxt from numpy only returning ints from a csv file full of floats

Tags: python, list, csv, numpy, variables

I currently have this project that I'm working on for my physics class involving taking data from a csv file and running some code to analyze the force of air resistance on a wiffle ball.  My data (from the csv file) is all floats with no strings in it, but I've had a problem with my code.  When I added the line for genfromtxt from numpy in my code, at first I thought the numbers in my csv file were added as strings, so I printed out the list it creates with it, and it showed that all my data was stored as integers.

This is the line that I used to import the file:

```
    x = genfromtxt('Xpos.csv', delimiter=',')
```

These are the first 10 numbers that are in my csv file:

```
0.659732735
0.746132896
0.806970832
0.881848293
0.966085435
1.017563689
1.101800832
1.190717816
1.256235594
1.317073531
```

These numbers show up in the printed list with the decimal places removed, so just 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1

Comment: We need to see a sample from the csv file to know what is happening.  Can you add the first four or five lines of the file to the question?

Comment: I added the first 10 numbers, and all I have is one column of numbers in my csv file.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  What is `x.dtype`?  Are you saying that if you do `print(x)` immediately after `x = genfromtxt('Xpos.csv', delimiter=',')`, the values in the output are just 0s and 1s?

Comment: If you open the csv with notepad, the decimal separator is also a dot? I mean..the default behaviour of `genfromtxt` is to infer floats, so the issue looks strange..

Answer (score 0):

If those ten numbers are exactly what's in your CSV file then that's why numpy is confused! You tell it to expect a delimiter ',' but in the file there are no commas anywhere! If you omit the delimiter argument from genfromtxt it should work fine.

This looks like a problem of lecturers liking CSV files (I've been there before!). They make everything comma separated variable files and then don't *actually put any commas in* so for new students who just start out they look up what csv means and get the wrong idea. It's stupid (on the lecturers part) it should just be a txt file, and none of this would happen.

Answer (score 0):

Omit the `delimiter=','` argument from genfromtxt. The CSV file actually has no commas in it so numpy is getting confused. If you give it no arguments it'll do fine on its own.

Comment: Whoops I answered twice! Could someone delete whichever answer is least helpful? It was not intentional!